# showing tasks collapsed

Tags: view, tasks, task-list

Is it possible to show tasks in a task list collapsed by default? And if so, is it possible to specify some tasks/sub-tasks as collapsed by default and others to be expanded by default?

Comment: Agreed - this is not what I'm looking for. I want to show only the top-level tasks with the sub-tasks collapsed (twisty pointing right rather than down).

Answer (score 1):

By default, it is collapsed as group

and to check this setting > open your view > modify the view .

- From the above ribbon, select modify view   >

[image]

- beside group check this setting

[image]

Regarding controlling to collapse some sub-tasks unfortunately it's not supported as  out of the box but you can create another view to show your subtasks and set it as expanded .

Comment: This option doesn't change whether my task list is collapsed or expanded (also, my task lists default to expanded so that sub-tasks are shown). I believe that the option you mentioned is only for list items that have been grouped, not for tasks and sub-tasks.